# Method access expection when attempting to convert struct to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, struct, arrays

I need to convert the following struct to a byte array:

```
[Serializable]
public struct newLeads
{
    public string id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
}
```

I'm trying to convert to the byte array with the following code:

```
public class ConvertStruct
{
    public static byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        int Length = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[Length];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Length);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytearray, 0, Length);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytearray;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the exception on line:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Length);
```

> Exception: Attempt by security transparent method 'Classes.ConvertStruct.ConvertStruct.StructureToByteArray(System.Object)' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Int32)' failed."}

My Question is? How can I fix this to avoid the exception and convert my simple struct into a `byte[]`?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I tried this in a console application and it works. I'm calling this from an asp.net page code-behind so that must have something to do with it, but I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check the size of the struct, don't box it.
2. Set an appropiate marshaling for string (taking from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10843370/402022) by [goric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940/goric)), whithout that, what you will get is the memory address of the strings in the byte array (not a good thing).

   ```
   [Serializable]
   public struct newLeads
   {
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
       public string id;
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
       public string first_name;
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
       public string last_name;
   }

   [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
   public static byte[] ToByteArray(newLeads value)
   {
       int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(newLeads));
       var result = new byte[length];
       IntPtr sourcePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
       Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, sourcePtr, false);
       Marshal.Copy(sourcePtr, result, 0, length);
       Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sourcePtr);
       return result;
   }
   ```

---

In your comment you said that this code fails sooner. Well, it uses a Security Permission Demand (as recommended for .NET 4) at it will check for the particular permision each time the method is called. You may try to execute it without it, and the expected result is what you got at the begining.

---

### The real answer

You must be running in a constrained enviroment, probably some kind of sandbox or a platform that doesn't support pointers. In that case, we may need to do the convertion by other means.

You said ASP.NET? so that's it.

In order to the convertion without pointers, try this technique:

```
//You will have to decide an encoding.
//If nto ASCII, try UTF8Encoding, UnicodeEncoding or (Hopefully not) UTF7Encoding
void Main()
{
    Encoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    newLeads target = GetNewLeads();
    byte[] id = EncodeString(target.id, encoding);
    byte[] first_name = EncodeString(target.first_name, encoding);
    byte[] last_name = EncodeString(target.last_name, encoding);
}

byte[] EncodeString(string str, Encoding encoding)
{
    byte[] data;
    if (ReferenceEquals(str, null))
    {
        data = new byte[0];
    }
    else
    {
        data = encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }
    return data;
}
```

At this point I need to know a bit more about your situation to give you a better solution, in particular who or what is going to read that byte array?. Anyway, you could encode the length of the strings, like so (reserving -1 for null):

```
byte[] EncodeString(string str, Encoding encoding)
{
    byte[] data;
    byte[] data_length;
    Union union = new Union();
    if (ReferenceEquals(str, null))
    {
        data = new byte[0];
        union.data = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        data = encoding.GetBytes(str);
        union.data = str.Length;
    }
    data_length = new byte[]{union.a, union.b, union.c, union.c};
    int length = data.Length;
    byte[] result = new byte[4 + data.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data_length, 0, result, 0, 4);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, result, 4, length);
    return result;
}

//I hope endianess doesn't bite
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] 
struct Union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int data;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public byte a;
    [FieldOffset(1)] 
    public byte b;
    [FieldOffset(2)] 
    public byte c;
    [FieldOffset(3)] 
    public byte d;
}
```

Lastly, we need to join those arrays. I know this can be optimized much more... (A good idea for that use MemoryStream and StreamWriter) Anyway, this is my first implementation [tested]:

```
byte[] ToByteArray(newLeads value)
{
    Encoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); //Choose some encoding
    byte[] id = EncodeString(value.id, encoding);
    byte[] first_name = EncodeString(value.first_name, encoding);
    byte[] last_name = EncodeString(value.last_name, encoding);
    byte[] result = new byte[id.Length + first_name.Length + last_name.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(id, 0, result, 0, id.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy
        (
            first_name,
            0,
            result,
            id.Length,
            first_name.Length
        );
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy
        (
            last_name,
            0,
            result,
            id.Length + first_name.Length,
            last_name.Length
        );
    return result;
}

byte[] EncodeString(string str, Encoding encoding)
{
    byte[] data;
    byte[] data_length;
    Union union = new Union();
    if (ReferenceEquals(str, null))
    {
        data = new byte[0];
        union.data = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        data = encoding.GetBytes(str);
        union.data = str.Length;
    }
    data_length = new byte[]{union.a, union.b, union.c, union.c};
    int length = data.Length;
    byte[] result = new byte[4 + data.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data_length, 0, result, 0, 4);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, result, 4, length);
    return result;
}

//I hope endianess doesn't bite
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] 
struct Union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int data;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public byte a;
    [FieldOffset(1)] 
    public byte b;
    [FieldOffset(2)] 
    public byte c;
    [FieldOffset(3)] 
    public byte d;
}
```

Note: I didn't use null terminated strings because I don't know what encoding you will end up using.

**Optimization**

Same logic, but implemented with streams (Union did not change)[tested].

```
byte[] ToByteArray(newLeads value)
{
    Encoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); //Choose some encoding
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    EncodeString(value.id, stream, encoding);
    EncodeString(value.first_name, stream, encoding);
    EncodeString(value.last_name, stream, encoding);
    int length = (int)stream.Length;
    byte[] result = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, result, 0, length);
    stream.Close();
    return result;
}

void EncodeString(string str, Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    Union union = new Union();
    if (ReferenceEquals(str, null))
    {
        union.data = -1;
        stream.Write(new byte[]{union.a, union.b, union.c, union.c}, 0, 4);
    }
    else
    {
        union.data = str.Length;
        stream.Write(new byte[]{union.a, union.b, union.c, union.c}, 0, 4);
        var tmp = encoding.GetBytes(str);
        stream.Write(tmp, 0, tmp.Length);
    }
}
```

---

### Reding the strings back

To get the data back, we begin by reading the length of the string (With the same type Union):

```
var newLeads = GetNewLeads();
var z= ToByteArray(newLeads); //we have the byteArray in z

var data = new MemoryStream(z); //Create an stream for convenience
//Use the union to get the length
var union = new Union()
    {
        a = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        b = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        c = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        d = (byte)data.ReadByte()
    };
Console.WriteLine(union.data); //the length of the first string
```

Our next step would be to read that many characters, to do that we will use an StreamReader:

```
var newLeads = GetNewLeads();
var z = ToByteArray(newLeads);

var data = new MemoryStream(z);
var union = new Union()
    {
        a = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        b = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        c = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        d = (byte)data.ReadByte()
    };
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string result = null;
if (union.data != -1)
{
    char[] finalChars = new char[union.data];
    var reader = new StreamReader(data, encoding);
    reader.Read(finalChars, 0, union.data);
    result = new string(finalChars);
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

With this we build a method to decode the strings:

```
string DecodeString(Stream data, Encoding encoding)
{   
    //TODO: You may want to validate that data and encoding are not null
    //or make this private
    var union = new Union()
    {
        a = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        b = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        c = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        d = (byte)data.ReadByte()
    };
    string result = null;
    if (union.data != -1)
    {
        char[] finalChars = new char[union.data];
        var reader = new StreamReader(data, encoding);
        reader.Read(finalChars, 0, union.data);
        result = new string(finalChars);
    }
    return result;
}

//Convenience method, not needed:

string DecodeString(byte[] data, Encoding encoding)
{
    //TODO: You may want to validate that data and encoding are not null
    //or make this private
    return DecodeString(new MemoryStream(data), encoding);
}
```

And finally the method to recover a newLeads (Again with the same Union type)[tested]:

```
newLeads FromByteArray(byte[] data)
{
    //TODO: Validate that data is not null
    Encoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); //Choose the same encoding
    newLeads result = new newLeads();
    var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(data), encoding);
    result.id = DecodeString(reader);
    result.first_name = DecodeString(reader);
    result.last_name = DecodeString(reader);
    reader.Close();
    return result;
}


//Changed to reuse StreamReader...
//Because closing it will close the underlying stream
string DecodeString(StreamReader reader)
{
    //TODO: You may want to validate that reader is not null
    //or make this private
    var data = reader.BaseStream;
    var union = new Union()
    {
        a = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        b = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        c = (byte)data.ReadByte(),
        d = (byte)data.ReadByte()
    };
    string result = null;
    if (union.data != -1)
    {
        char[] finalChars = new char[union.data];
        reader.Read(finalChars, 0, union.data);
        result = new string(finalChars);
    }
    return result;
}

//Convenience method, not needed:

string DecodeString(byte[] data, Encoding encoding)
{
    //TODO: You may want to validate that data and encoding are not null
    //or make this private
    return DecodeString(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(data), encoding));
}
```

Comment: yeah, in the current form ToByteArray throws this exception as soon as it's hit: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Comment: @James let me know if there anything I'm missing, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: @James added the reverse conversion. Can I get accepted answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your struct, mark your strings with proper `MarshalAs` attributes ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx)):

```
[Serializable]
public struct newLeads
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
    public string id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
    public string first_name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5000)]
    public string last_name;
}
```

Make sure that the `SizeConst` value is large enough to cover the maximum length of data you're going to be using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be able to mark your method as `SecurityCritical`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264475.aspx